# What exactly happens when you write a function in rust and call it in the a JavaScript file?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

Apparently making a web application using rust and wasm make it run faster. Your rust code uses web assembly as a compilation target and your rust code is compiled into web assembly, this web assembly is run in the browsers web assembler machine , correct me if I am wrong

You can write rust functions and call them a JavaScript file. Does this call the web assembly code that your rust function was turned into ?

Comment: Yes, that is all pretty much how that works. Is there something a bit more specific that you're interested in? Either way I'd encourage you to look through the [wasm-bindgen guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/introduction.html) for Rust-Javascript integration and if you want to know about the nitty-gritty details there's an [Internal Design section](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/contributing/design/exporting-rust.html) that gives a brief overview for how the glue functions on the Rust and Javascript side are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently making a web application using rust and wasm make it run faster.

Performance is up to a lot of things, and "just do it in wasm" doesn't magically improve things. In fact, there's two main areas that can cause trouble:

- WASM binaries tend to be larger than equivalent JS. This can be somewhat mitigated by compression and careful compiler flags, but since your website won't won't work before the code is loaded, it is a trade-off. WASM wins if you need to do something heavy/repeatedly.
- Calls between WASM and JS can't be inlined. (Which sometimes causes misunderstandings about what kind of performance to expect, e.g.: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331830/why-is-my-webassembly-function-slower-than-the-javascript-equivalent) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173979/why-is-webassembly-function-almost-300-time-slower-than-same-js-function/48181100#48181100) - the performance of calls has been [improved](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/10/calls-between-javascript-and-webassembly-are-finally-fast-%F0%9F%8E%89/), but it still doesn't ccome close to inlining for small functions.) On top of that, WASM [doesn't](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/where-is-webassembly-now-and-whats-next/) offer direct access to the HTML DOM, you need to go through JS. So if your code mostly does DOM modification, WASM loses.

Imho, a relatively interesting case study of WASM performance is `source-map`. It does some relatively heavy string parsing.

1. It was [first](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/01/oxidizing-source-maps-with-rust-and-webassembly/) rewritten in Rust/WASM for a significant performance improvement
2. [Then](https://mrale.ph/blog/2018/02/03/maybe-you-dont-need-rust-to-speed-up-your-js.html) an absolute master of JS performance came and showed that the same performance could have been attained in JS (But certainly not in idiomatic JS. - Given the existence of asm.js, this is not so surprising.)
3. [Finally](https://fitzgeraldnick.com/2018/02/26/speed-without-wizardry.html), some of the techniques showed in 2. were ported to Rust, which finally gave the WASM version a slight speed advantage.

So what's the conclusion? WASM might give you better performance if you have something heavy to compute which happens to be difficult to optimize for JS engines.
For further reading, [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/what-makes-webassembly-fast/) series gives a nice overview of the why, how, and what to expect for WASM.

Comment: Looks like you've put effort into this. Maybe post a question that this does answer, then answer it with this answer? (Link to the Q&A on this question)

Comment: Agreed, the content here is good, but misplaced. Answers are for answers, not long comments.